# jQuery if conditions not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, if-statement

What I want to do in the code is, I will calculate the sum of all fields (input type number fields). After summing up, I am going to compare their different ranges with if/else statement. My code is not working.

**HTML CODE**

```
<p class="line-item-property__field">
   <label for="B1">B1 (Min. 50)</label>
   <input required="" id="B1" style="width:120px; max-width:100%;" value="0" min="0" step="50" name="properties[B1]" type="number" class="inp">
</p>
<p class="line-item-property__field">
   <label for="B2">B2 (Min. 50)</label>
   <input id="B2" style="width:120px; max-width:100%;" value="0" min="0" step="50" name="properties[B2]" type="number" class="inp">
</p>
<p class="line-item-property__field">
   <label for="B3">B3 (Min. 50)</label>
   <input id="B3" style="width:120px; max-width:100%;" value="0" min="0" step="50" name="properties[B3]" type="number" class="inp">
</p>
<p class="line-item-property__field">
   <label for="B4">B4 (Min. 50)</label>
   <input id="B4" style="width:120px; max-width:100%;" value="0" min="0" step="50" name="properties[B4]" type="number" class="inp">
</p>
<p class="line-item-property__field">
   <label for="B5">B5 (Min. 50)</label>
   <input id="B5" style="width:120px; max-width:100%;" value="0" min="0" step="50" name="properties[B5]" type="number" class="inp">
</p>
<p class="line-item-property__field">
   <label for="B6">B6 (Min. 50)</label>
   <input id="B6" style="width:120px; max-width:100%;" value="0" min="0" step="50" name="properties[B6]" type="number" class="inp">
</p>
```

**My jQuery code**

```
$(".inp").change(function(){
   var sum = 0;
   $(".inp").each(function(){
       sum += parseInt($(this).val());
   });

   if(sum => 50 && sum < 100){
       alert("in between range");
   }
   else{
       alert("Out of the range");
   }
});
```

**NOTE: The sum is correctly calculated but the problem is the `if` condition doesn't work properly.**

Comment: You are __not__ using correct operator Use `>=` not `=>`

Comment: ___NOTE: Sum is calculated fine but the problem is in if condition it is not works properly.___ --- make it more clear

Comment: Voting to close it as TYPO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`=>` need to be `>=`

Like below:-

```
if(sum >= 50 && sum < 100){
  alert("in between range");
}
```

Comment: These are typos don't answer them instead vote to close

Comment: @Satpal  close the question and i will delete my answer

Comment: I alone can't close the question, You can delete the answer and vote to close

Comment: @Satpal  i have already voted to close.Asap question will close i will delete my answer.